# Meteor: unable to grab value of radio input

Tags: jquery, meteor, radio-button

I've been unable to get the value of a radio button to save into the db. I can get text input and select input just fine.

It's the icon property that isn't working.

Here's my first javascript attempt:

```
Template.goalAdd.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var goal = {
            category: $(e.target).find('[name=category]').val(),
            goal: $(e.target).find('[name=goal]').val(),
            icon: $(e.target).find('input[name=icon]:checked').val()
        }

        Meteor.call('goal', goal, function(error, id) {
            if (error)
                return alert(error.reason);

            Router.go('/');
        });
    }
});
```

In that version I've also tried:

```
icon: $(e.target).find('input[name=icon]:checked', '#addgoalform').val()
```

and

```
icon: $(e.target).find('[name=icon]:checked').val()
```

Here's my second js attempt, creating an array and using each:

```
Template.goalAdd.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var icons = [];
        $('input[name=icon]:checked').each(function() {
            icons.push($(this).val());
        });

        var goal = {
            category: $(e.target).find('[name=category]').val(),
            goal: $(e.target).find('[name=goal]').val(),
            icon: icons
        }

        Meteor.call('goal', goal, function(error, id) {
            if (error)
                return alert(error.reason);

            Router.go('/');
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the html:

```
    <div>
        <label for="icon">Icon</label>
        <div id="icon" class="controls uncheckit">
            <ul class="iconradios">
                <li class="icomoonli">
                    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="user">
                    <label class="radio"><i class="fa-medium icon icon-user" ></i></label>
                </li>
                <li class="icomoonli">
                    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="users">
                    <label class="radio"><i class="fa-medium icon icon-users" ></i></label>
                </li>
                <li class="icomoonli">
                    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="boss">
                    <label class="radio"><i class="fa-medium icon icon-boss" ></i></label>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't in the template js or the html after all. I'd forgotten to add that property to a Meteor method for this template.